# Meteor-Simple-Schema Insert Schema directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, simple-schema

I am validating my data using simple schema and have defaultValues for two fields. During this process simpleSchema validates, cleans and adds necessary values to the data. So the question is how can I store this schema directly into my database.

I have gone over the docs https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema multiple times but don't see anything related to this.

Right now I am validating my data and extracting each property manually, which kinda sucks.

```
    let schema = this.validateCar(data);
    data.live = data.live || schema.get('live', 'defaultValue');
    data.active = data.active || schema.get('active', 'defaultValue');
```

Comment: What happens when you try to store it? what's the error?

Comment: Its basically a simpleSchema object with functions and transformed data.

Comment: Are you using `mongoose`?

Comment: No. Not sure if that would make any difference.

Comment: This is what I see in the docs: `This value will be injected into the object by a call to mySimpleSchema.clean() with getAutovalues: true. Default values are set only when cleaning non-modifier objects.`

Comment: Yeah thay would still give me simpleSchema object. I believe by defaul simpleSchema runs the clean methods such as trim, etc.

Comment: If you *attach* your schema to your collection then it will run automatically on insert/update/upsert. You don't need to validate field by field.